# Rounding to a fixed relative precision

Tags: java, floating-point, rounding

I get number representing strings like

```
248.03500000066338
313.44999999979470
4.2346999999
```

and I need to round them to something like

```
248.035
313.45
4.2347
```

while keeping a fixed *relative* precision of let's say 6 significant figures. I could do it using `Math.log10`, computing what absolute precision is needed, and rounding correspondingly, but I wonder if there's a simple way.

---

Ideally, the resulting number should be such that it does not produce the trailing nines when converted to string, but this is not needed and maybe impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be the most performant solution but I think this is the easiest one:

```
BigDecimal input = new BigDecimal("248.03500000066338");
double rounded = input.round(new MathContext(6)).doubleValue();
```

Comment: Diky Kubo. Works like charm and the speed is more than good enough.